# How to save an Outlook attachment to SharePoint?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I created a function in Excel to save a specified attachment (Excel file) from a specified email to a file location.

My organisation has moved all of our files to Sharepoint. I tried to update my function using the SharePoint path, but it fails to save the attachment.

```vb
Function OpenEMailAttachment(Path As String, FileName As String, FindSubj As String, FindAttachName As String, SubFolder As Object)
    
    Dim oOlAp As Object, oOlns As Object, oOlInb As Object
    Dim oOlItm As Object, oOlAtch As Object
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim sSubj As String
    
    '~~> Outlook Variables for email
    ' Other options for email properties are:
    ' eSender = oOlItm.SenderEmailAddress
    ' dtRecvd = oOlItm.ReceivedTime
    ' dtSent = oOlItm.CreationTime
    ' sMsg = oOlItm.Body

    '~~> Get Outlook instance
    Set oOlAp = GetObject(, "Outlook.application")
    Set oOlns = oOlAp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oOlInb = oOlns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    
    '~~> Store the relevant info in the variables
    For Each oOlItm In oOlInb.Items

        sSubj = oOlItm.Subject
        
        Debug.Print sSubj & "-->" & FindSubj
            
            If sSubj Like FindSubj Then
                
                Debug.Print "Opening attachment"
                
                If oOlItm.Attachments.Count <> 0 Then
                    
                    For Each oOlAtch In oOlItm.Attachments
                    
                    '~~> Download the attachment
                        If oOlAtch.FileName Like FindAttachName Then
                            
                            
                            
                            Debug.Print Path & FileName
                            oOlAtch.SaveAsFile Path & FileName
                            Debug.Print Path & oOlAtch.FileName
                            oOlItm.UnRead = False
                            DoEvents
                            oOlItm.Save
                            On Error Resume Next
                                oOlItm.Move SubFolder
                            On Error GoTo 0

                        End If
                    Next
                
                End If

            End If
    Next

    '~~> FilePath is the file that we earlier downloaded
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Path & FileName)
    
    OpenEMailAttachment = FileName

End Function
```

The path I specified is like https://MyOrg.sharepoint.com/teams/FolderName/
and the FileName like File%20Name.xlsx

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
Sub copyFilesTo_Sharepoint()
    Dim srcFolder As String
    Dim dstFolder As String

    ' source path
    srcFolder = "WriteYourSourcePathHere"
    
    ' destination path
    dstFolder = "\\MyOrg.sharepoint.com\teams\FolderName"
        
    ' copies all Excel files starting with 'myfiles' with extension 'xslx'
    Call fs_cpyFilesToFolder(srcFolder, dstFolder, "myfile*.xlsx")
End Sub

Sub fs_cpyFilesToFolder(srcPath As String, dstPath As String, Optional FileExt As String = "*.xlsx")
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    ' checks if source path has a '\'
    If Right(srcPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        srcPath = srcPath & "\"
    End If

    ' checks if source path exists
    If fso.FolderExists(srcPath) = False Then
        MsgBox srcPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' checks if destination path exists
    If fso.FolderExists(dstPath) = False Then
        MsgBox dstPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' copies files to sharepoint
    fso.CopyFile Source:=srcPath & FileExt, Destination:=dstPath
End Sub
```